# New Chat window

Tags: javascript, html

i've got a chat (without any design until now)

```
<div id="chatHtml">
    <input type="text" id="input-text-chat" placeholder="Enter Text Chat">
    <div id="chat-container">
        <div id=chatOutput class="chat-output"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now I have a button, which calls ja javascript function to open a new window

```
<button type="button" v-on:click="openChat">open chat</button>

openChat: function() {
    win = top.consoleRef = window.open('', 'myconsole',
        'width=350,height=250' +
        ',menubar=0' +
        ',toolbar=1' +
        ',status=0' +
        ',scrollbars=1' +
        ',resizable=1')
    chat = document.getElementById("chatHtml").innerHTML;
    win.document.write(chat);
}
```

And last there is the code that the chat is working

```
document.getElementById('input-text-chat').onkeyup = function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode != 13) return;
    // removing trailing/leading whitespace
    //   this.value = this.value.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
    if (!this.value.length) return
    connection.send(this.value);
    console.log(connection.send);
    console.log(this.value);
    appendDIV(this.value);
    this.value = '';
};
var chatContainer = document.querySelector('.chat-output');

function appendDIV(event) {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = event.data || event;
    chatContainer.insertBefore(div, chatContainer.firstChild);
    div.tabIndex = 0;
    div.focus();
    document.getElementById('input-text-chat').focus();
    win.document.write(chatContainer.innerHTML);
}
```

---

**My Problem:**

The chat is not working in the new window but on the "index window" it is.
Im completely new to javascript and i dont know whats the problem. 
I thik its because of the ID's or sth. 
Can sb help me, that i can use the chat in the new window? 
Thanks :)

Comment: its not working because it's doesn't have bind event yet

Comment: can you explain it more exactly? I'm really new to this and i dont even not what a binding is in javascript.

Comment: I mean events which mean. It read it somethings happen(touch) your element example click, hover, mouse up, etc

Comment: but it works, i just need the ID of the input/output box in the new window. I dont know if i can realize it with events.

Answer (score 0):

the input of your new page hasn't have event yet so bind it's event

just add this

```
openChat: function(){
    win =top.consoleRef=window.open('','myconsole',
    'width=350,height=250'
    +',menubar=0'
    +',toolbar=1'
    +',status=0'
    +',scrollbars=1'
    +',resizable=1')
    chat = document.getElementById("chatHtml").innerHTML;
    win.document.write(chat);

    win.document.getElementById('input-text-chat').onkeyup = function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode != 13) return;
        // removing trailing/leading whitespace
     //   this.value = this.value.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
        if (!this.value.length) return
        connection.send(this.value);
        console.log(connection.send);
        console.log(this.value);
        appendDIV(this.value);
        this.value = '';
    };

}
```

after

```
win.document.write(chatContainer.innerHTML);
```

also it's better if you put a name it that event to lessen your code

Comment: I'm still not able to write in the new window and the line : win.document.write(chatContainer.innerHTML); is wrong, that was just a try, forgot to delete that.

Comment: could you screenshot your JS

Comment: The whole js file?

Comment: just the one I told you to add

Comment: let's continue in chat

Comment: I told you to add the event after here win.document.write(chatContainer.innerHTML);

Comment: I did that and it didnt work, i wasnt able to write. So i delete it again, sorry that i havent told u

Comment: I just restored the old version, like its in the post. 
so that the one chat is working but the other not.

Comment: did you try adding to function after win.document.write(chat);?

Comment: I can write now, sorry i missunderstood you, im really sorry man! But now it isnt shown in the new Window, i only can write and send it.

Comment: I can write it in the new window and its shown in the old

Comment: Now it works :
https://postimg.org/image/b9nfchs29/
but the connection can not get the function :
https://postimg.org/image/kiplmm0y9/

Comment: @mantaplatte now mark it as answer and vote up so I can receive my reputation